Scratch implementation of ridge regression
I am trying to implement Ridge regression but I feel like I am missing something with the Python operators. Here is my code:
import numpy as np


x = np.random.rand(10, 2)  
y = np.random.rand(10, 1)  
lambda_reg = 0.1  
alpha = 0.1  
num_iterations = 100000  


X_train = np.hstack((np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)), x))

def ridge_regression_gradient_descent(X, y, lambda_reg, alpha, num_iterations):
n, p = X.shape  
B = np.zeros(p)  
# Gradient descent loop
for _ in range(num_iterations):
    y_pred = X.dot(B).reshape(-1, 1)  
    gradient_B0 = - (1/n) * np.sum(y - y_pred)  
    gradient_B = - (1/n) * (X[:, 1:].T @ (y - y_pred)) +  
    lambda_reg * B[1:].reshape(-1, 1)  # Gradients for B1 to Bp   

    B[0] -= alpha * gradient_B0  
    B[1:] -= alpha * gradient_B.reshape(-1)  
    return B

B = ridge_regression_gradient_descent(X_train, y, lambda_reg, alpha, num_iterations)
print(B)

Is anyone able to see what I am doing wrong?
I tried multiple changes in the code on the matrix multiplications + also reshaping everything in the right format. I get actually 3 Beta's so this is ok but I don't get anything close to what I get with the formula: B = (X.T X + lambda * I)^-1 * X.T Y

Some observations about your optimization function:

Why are you dividing by N? You're making your gradient smaller than necessary, and you're not applying that scaling to the second term in your gradient, changing the relationship between the components of your gradient (making the residual-driven term much smaller than the coefficient-driven term).
Why are you calculating your B0 and B1 gradients separately? You can take the gradient in terms of all of B using all of X instead of fragmenting your solution. You've applied regularization to B[1:] but not to B[0].

Here is an amended solution for you, without dividing the residual-driven term by n, and adding regularization to B[0] as well:
def ridge_regression_gradient_descent(X, y, lambda_reg, alpha, num_iterations):
    n, p = X.shape  
    B = np.zeros(p)  
    # Gradient descent loop
    for _ in range(num_iterations):
        y_pred = X.dot(B).reshape(-1, 1)  
        gradient_B0 = -np.sum(y - y_pred)  + lambda_reg * B[0]
        gradient_B = -(X[:, 1:].T @ (y - y_pred)) + lambda_reg * B[1:].reshape(-1, 1)  # Gradients for B1 to Bp   

        B[0] -= alpha * gradient_B0  
        B[1:] -= alpha * gradient_B.reshape(-1)  
    return B


B = ridge_regression_gradient_descent(X_train, y, lambda_reg, alpha=.001, num_iterations=10000)
print(B)

> [ 0.53250528 -0.21478985 -0.15051757]

Indeed you can check the output of this function by calculating B explicitly as you've described.
beta = np.linalg.inv(X_train.T@X_train+np.identity(X_train.shape[1])*lambda_reg)@(X_train.T@y)

print(beta)

> [[ 0.53256638]
 [-0.21485239]
 [-0.15058472]]

Here is a separate solution calculating the gradient in terms of all of B using all of X, it accomplishes the same thing, but it is more straightforward and efficient:
def descent(X,y,lambda_reg,alpha,num_iterations):

    B = np.zeros((X.shape[1],1))
    
    for _ in range(num_iterations):

        grad = (X.T@((X@B).reshape(y.shape) - y) + lambda_reg*B)

        B = B - alpha*grad

    return B


B = descent(X_train, y, lambda_reg, alpha=.1, num_iterations=10000)
print(B)

> [[ 0.53256638]
 [-0.21485239]
 [-0.15058472]]


I have some remarks / extra questions related to your comments:


Ridge regression does not apply the regularization term to the the intercept B0 when taking the MSE right ? So why should I multiply by B0 in the derivation of MSE to B0 ?


When deriving the MSE we always have a 1/n before and after deriving. Indeed those terms could be neglected since we look at the derivative equal to 0 but it is not wrong to include them, right ?



@MelvinCurraj to your questions, all coefficients, including the intercept, are regularized under regularization. The intercept is just another coefficient, applied to a column of ones. Your X matrix could just as easily include all variables and additionally a column of ones. Your cost function is the sun of squared errors, not the mean squared error. The difference in unregularized regression is meaningless, but when regularization is applied, the difference is important. This comment won’t allow enough characters to explain everything, but feel free to message me other Q’s if you’d like.

@MelvinCurraj typo above: “sum of squared errors”
